# How to use Intent Flags in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the knowledge of different types of flags in intent but unable to use in my activities. Can anybody explain me,

- How can we finish an activity and alternatively ?
- How to manipulate the activity stack with the help of intent flags.

Comment: what do you mean by manipulating the activity stack?

Comment: It simply means how we can move or use different activities from the stack by using flags

Comment: Have you check here ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 15):

You can call `finish()` in your activity to finish it.
There are flags which you can use in this time depending on your requirement.

Here is how they work, from [Android documentation about Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

> If set in any intent that is passed to your startActivity(), it will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, all old activities are finished.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

> If set in any intent that is passed to your startActivity(), and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the old activity as a new Intent.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

> If set in any intent that is passed to your startActivity(), this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

> If set in any intent that is passed to your startActivity(), the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

You can use it like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Sample.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

For further clarifications you can check also [Back Stack and Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish activity, you can call the method finish() from that activity.

There are different kinds of flags available for activity:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

you can use then witn Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for any activities setFlag method parameter.

For more:
[Tasks and Back Stacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and 
[Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Hopefully it may help you.